# Ignore _id from Mongo Query spring framework library

Tags: mongodb, spring-boot

I am to run following query for my micro service through Mongo template.

> find({"accId": 1234}, {"_id":0}).

I am using Query and Criteria libraries. I have tried various combinations of the addCriteria but I am unable to reach the desired query.

Any inputs or guidance here ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
@Autowired
private MongoTemplate mongoTemplate;
...

Query q = new Query(Criteria.where("accId").is(1234));
q.fields().exclude("_id");
List<YourClass> result = mongoTemplate.find(q, YourClass.class);
```

https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/mongodb/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/mongodb/core/query/Query.html

Comment: where to add accId filter ?

Comment: @earl Check it again please

Comment: Gives Type mismatch: cannot convert from Field to Query

Comment: @earl My bad, we need to exclude it in separate line